# copy last modified files from one bucket into an other bucket using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to copy last modified files from one GCS bucket to another.
Let's assume that input bucket is :

```
gs://input-bucket/object
```

and target bucket is :

```
gs://target-bucket/object
```

I want to  copy files last files of today : 
I wrote

```
gsutil ls -l gs://renault-ftt-vll-dfp/complex-files/PAN/TRM    | sort -k2n | tail -n5   | sort -k2n | tail -n5
```

But this is not complete. my aime is to copy the files which were last modified today from input bucket to target bucket. 
Any help with this please ? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to do this easily in gsutil at the moment but it is feasible using the terminal.

`gsutil -m ls -l gs://input-bucket | grep $(date -I) | sed 's/.*\(gs:\/\/\)/\1/''| gsutil cp -I gs://target-bucket/`

To break it down:

`gsutil -m ls -l gs://input-bucket` - This will list all objects within the input-bucket

example line:  `29  2018-11-27T15:43:24Z  gs://input-bucket/README.md`

`grep $(date -I)` - Finds all lines that contain today's date. (find all objects modified today)

`sed 's/.*\(gs:\/\/\)/\1/''` - This will remove everything up to where `gs://` starts so it will change the line from `29  2018-11-27T15:43:24Z  gs://input-bucket/README.md` to `gs://input-bucket/README.md`

`gsutil cp -I gs://target-bucket/` - Copy it to the target storage bucket, the -I option allows us to input the list of files to copy from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do that with gsutil, but I did this beautiful script in python for you:

```py
import subprocess
import re
import datetime

child = subprocess.Popen('gsutil ls -l gs://<YOUR_BUCKET> | sort -k2n',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = child.communicate()[0]

datepattern = re.compile("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
matcher = datepattern.search(output)

for line in output.splitlines():
    datepattern = re.compile("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
    matcher = datepattern.search(line)
    if matcher:
        if matcher.group(0) == datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):

            filebucket = line[line.index("gs://") + len("gs://"):]
            child = subprocess.Popen("gsutil cp gs://"+filebucket+" gs://<YOUR_DESTINATION_BUCKET>",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            outputCopy=child.communicate()[0]
            print outputCopy
```

Just edit the "< YOUR_BUCKET >" and "< YOUR_DESTINATION_BUCKET >" fields and run this normally, it should copy all the files that have been modified today to your destination bucket.