# Check when GCS storage bucket directory contents were last modified using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am transferring a large number of files to a google cloud storage bucket. I would like to make sure the transfer is continuing uninterrupted by checking the last time the directory in the bucket I am transferring files to was modified using `gsutil` and the Cloud Shell Terminal.

What is the best way to do this? Using `find` is not an option because it's not supported by `gsutil`. An alternative approach is to filter the output of `ls` by date: `gsutil -m ls -l gs://my_bucket/my_directory | grep $(date -I)`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500085/copy-last-modified-files-from-one-bucket-into-an-other-bucket-using-gsutil). However, this isn't very useful because it returns thousands of files modified in the last day. I've tried modifying the `date` command to `date -I'hours'` and `date -I'minutes'` to get files modified in the last hour or the last minute, but this does not seem to work as expected because nothing is returned. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this without checking the creation/modification time of the objects within the "directory". This is because GCS is not actually a filesystem that uses real directories. It's an object storage system that supports the `/` character in object names. Thus, if you have two objects named `my/files/a` and `my/files/b`, there are not really two directories in GCS named `my` and `files`. Rather, you have two objects that share a common prefix, `my/files/`.

Answer (score 1):

Directories do not exist. Cloud Storage namespace is flat. That means there is no directory entry to check.

The contents of objects in Google Cloud Storage cannot be modified (immutable). Therefore there is no real `last modified date`.

However, objects have additional attributes called `storage class` and `metadata` that can be modified. Those items do have modification dates as they can be changed: `timeStorageClassUpdated`, and `updated`.

An object either exists in Cloud Storage or does not. There are no partial copies/uploads. For example, if you upload a file and the upload fails, the object will be deleted, and it will have not been visible during the upload operation. There are exceptions to this but require specific API features.

[Resource representation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource-representations)